# MYSQL GROUP BY on 2 Tables with MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, max

I have 2 mysql tables:

**record** table:
[image]

and
**race** table:

[image]

I want to select the records from the 1st table group by **id_Race** but only the MAX from column "**secs**".

I tried the following but didnt work:

```
$query = "SELECT   rec.RecordsID,rec.id_Athlete,rec.date_record,rec.id_Race,rec.placeevent,rec.mins,rec.secs,rec.huns,rec.distance,rec.records_text,r.name,MAX(rec.secs)
      FROM records AS rec INNER JOIN race AS r ON r.RaceID=rec.id_Race WHERE (id_Athlete=$u_athlete) GROUP BY rec.id_Race;";
```

($u_athlete is a variable i get from _SESSION)

Can you help me about that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) like `MAX` and select all fields, you are forced to include all selected fields that are not affected by the `MAX` inside the `GROUP BY` clause.

Though you can use a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) like `ROW_NUMBER` that will group by specifically on `id_Race` and order by the secs column in a descendent way (so that the highest value of `secs` will be associated with `row_number=1`).

Afterwards you can select the rows which have `row_number=1` and the `id_Athlete` you pass using the variable.

```
SELECT
    rec.RecordsID,
    rec.id_Athlete,
    rec.date_record,
    rec.id_Race,
    rec.placeevent,
    rec.mins,
    rec.secs,
    rec.huns,
    rec.distance,
    rec.records_text,
    race.name,
FROM  
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_race ORDER BY secs) rank
    FROM 
        record 
    ) rec
INNER JOIN 
    race race
ON 
    race.RaceID=rec.id_Race 
WHERE 
    rec.rank = 1
AND 
    rec.id_Athlete = $u_athlete;
```